# Is there a way to order a list with named elements that represent numbers in R so that it returns the name of the elements ratehr than their value?

Tags: r

I have assigned 6 different numbers to 6 different elements called num1, num2, num3, num4, num5, num6, respectively. Then I made a list containing these 6 elements and called it Numbers. Now I want to find a way to order that list according to size from highest to lowest so that it returns the names of the elements (so num1,..., num6) rather than their values. I tried the order() command but this returns the values rather then the names:

```
num1 <- 2

num2 <- 1

num3 <- 3

num4 <- 7

num5 <- 8

num6 <- 4

Numbers <- c(num1, num2, num3, num4, num5, num6)


Numbers[order(Numbers, decreasing = TRUE)]
```

As I said this returns the values for the elements in order, however, I need something that returns the element names in order, so in this case: num5, num4, num6, num3, num1, num2.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
v1 <- sort(unlist(mget(paste0('num', seq(6)))), decreasing = TRUE)
names(v1)
#[1] "num5" "num4" "num6" "num3" "num1" "num2"
```